# sqlite manager firefox extensions does not show all the tables

Tags: core-data, browser

I'm using the sqlite manager add-on on firefox to check the sqlite file of my iOS app but the problem is that I have 45 tables in my core data file and the sqlite manager does not display them all, I dont know why!!

does anyone have any clue?

Thanks,

Comment: I tried a couple of other browser and I got the same result so it seems the issue in the file

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Are you seeing some kind of Core Data problem that you're trying to fix?

Comment: I'm just trying to see the data in the sqlite file becuase I encountered an issue with the digits of a number in a column of a table that is not appearing when attaching the sqlite to any sqlite browser, that's why I need to know if I did something wrong or it is how core data works